# D3JS Symbols Style Transition

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a line chart with symbols in d3js. I need to understand how can I get the applied symbol type, so that I change the style properties according to an input. Also currently when I am changing the color of the symbols they disappear from the chart area. Currently I am fetching the symbols from an array, however I want to retrieve them based on the one applied on the chart as the user can change the symbol type on the chart and thus the current retrieval from the array will not work. I am adding additional code to show the creation of the symbols. i am following the following example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

I am adding the code where I change the symbol based on user input. It has the same filter that is used to change the color, however this one works perfectly and displays the symbol along with the color change if i had changed the color prior to changing the symbol.

```
var color = function(i) {
    var colors2 = ["#CA0000", "#A2005C",
                  "#7EBD00", "#007979"];
    return colors2[i % colors2.length]
    };


var symbol = function(i) {
    var symbols = ["circle", "diamond", "square",
                   "triangle-up", "triangle-down", "cross"];
    return d3.svg.symbol()
             .size(81)
             .type(symbols[i % symbols.length]);
};

cities.forEach(function(dataset, i) {



    svg.selectAll(".point" )
    .data(dataset.values)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr('id','symbolTrack2'+i)
    .attr("class", "point" + i)
    .attr("fill", color(i))
    .attr("stroke", "transparent")
    .attr("d", symbol(i).size(100))
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.date) +
                          "," + y(d.temperature) + ")";
    });
}

$scope.changeSymbolcolor =function(d) {
         var newHeight = $scope.config.symbolColor;
         d3.selectAll("path")
          .filter(function(d,i) { 
              var check;
              if(this.id == selectedIdForChange) {
                  check = true; 
                 } else {
                  check = false;
                 }

              return check; })
          .transition().attr("d", function(d,i){return symbol(i)}).attr('fill',newHeight);
         };



$scope.chartSymbolChange=function() {
         var newSymbol = $scope.config.chartSymbol;
         d3.selectAll("path")
          .filter(function(d,i) { 
              var check;
              if(this.id == selectedIdForChange) {
                  check = true; 
                 } else {
                  check = false;
                 }

              return check; })
          .transition().delay(0).duration(1000).attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(newSymbol));
         };
```

Comment: some more code? probably a working version?

Comment: Symbols disappear from the chart area because you are filtering them out from changeSymbolcolor function

Comment: Hi Raj, I am filtering the ones that I need to change, and then applying the changes on them. The rest are being displayed normally. The same filter works for other items,

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer this question concretely.  One thing jumps out at me though -- `d3.selectAll("path")` is probably wrong.  Your plot will have lots and lots of `paths` that aren't symbols (the axis, the line segments).  You probably want `svg.selectAll('.point' + selectedIdForChange)` where selectIdForChange is the index of the line you want to change symbols for.  Here's a little [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFlvwacVOPeUy1v7jrel?p=preview) I started to put together.

Comment: Thanks for the input Mark. Will implement the same. However my question is regarding the change in style of the symbols. Whenever I try to change the color, the symbol changes to circles. As mentioned, suppose I have changed the symbol to a diamond shape and then would like change the color of the same. For this I would need to know which symbol has been implemented at the point which has been selected for change, and that is what I am unable to retrieve. Is there any way I can retrieve the symbol that has been implemented at the point.

Comment: Got the answer. No need to retrieve the symbol type to implement the style change. Just filter the path and apply the style change.