# D3js make the text label draggable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following this example http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/ for making a bar chart. What I would like to do along with making the chart is make the `data-labels` draggable. How can I achieve that? I have tried calling the on drag behavior without any result. All I am getting is `NaN` as the input for the `transform` function.

```
var w = 600;
var h = 250;

var dataset = [ 
{ key: 0, value: 5 },
{ key: 1, value: 10 },
{ key: 2, value: 13 },
{ key: 3, value: 19 },
{ key: 4, value: 21 },
{ key: 5, value: 25 },
{ key: 6, value: 22 },
{ key: 7, value: 18 },
{ key: 8, value: 15 },
{ key: 9, value: 13 },
{ key: 10, value: 11 },
{ key: 11, value: 12 },
{ key: 12, value: 15 },
{ key: 13, value: 20 },
{ key: 14, value: 18 },
{ key: 15, value: 17 },
{ key: 16, value: 16 },
{ key: 17, value: 18 },
{ key: 18, value: 23 },
{ key: 19, value: 25 } ];

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05); 

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d.value;})])
            .range([0, h]);

var key = function(d) {
return d.key;
};

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

//Create bars
svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(dataset, key)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value);
})
.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
})
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
})

 //Tooltip
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) +          xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 14;

    //Update Tooltip Position & value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
        .style("top", yPosition + "px")
        .select("#value")
        .text(d.value);
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false)
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
    //Remove the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
})  ;

//Create labels
svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset, key)
.call(drag2) 
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
})
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
})
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
  })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");

 var sortOrder = false;
var sortBars = function () {
sortOrder = !sortOrder;

sortItems = function (a, b) {
    if (sortOrder) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    }
    return b.value - a.value;
};

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
})
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
});

svg.selectAll('text')
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
})
    .duration(1000)
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.value;
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
});
};
// Add the onclick callback to the button
d3.select("#sort").on("click", sortBars);
d3.select("#reset").on("click", reset);
function randomSort() {


svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
})
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
});

svg.selectAll('text')
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
})
    .duration(1000)
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.value;
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
});
}

var drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function(d,i) {
    d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", function( d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;

    return "translate(" + [ d3.event.dx,d3.event.dy ] + ")"
});

 function reset() {
 svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b){
        return a.key - b.key;
    })
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
    });

    svg.selectAll('text')
    .sort(function(a, b){
        return a.key - b.key;
    })
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.value;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
     return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
     })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
});
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by the dta-label? The label with count `5`, `10`... ? Do you want to drag them independently?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how you want the drag function to behave, So I have made it work. You can simply do whatever you want inside the `.on('drag')` function. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv40gz5b/1/). Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

EDIT : Now you can move the text label along the `y-axis`. Instead of `transform` I just change the `y` attribute of the `text` with the `mouse`.

```
//Create labels
svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset, key)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
                .origin(function () {
                    var t = d3.select(this);
                    return {x : t.attr('x'), y: t.attr('y')}
                })
                .on('drag', function (d, i) {
                    console.log('dragging text');

                    d3.select(this).attr('y', function () {

                        return d3.mouse(this)[1];

                    });


                }))
;
```

Comment: I want to re position them once i have dragged them. Lets say at the top of the bar chart, or at the bottom of it.

Comment: Do you want to drag it along the bar? from top to bottom?

Comment: Yes, Fazwan. That would be great.

Comment: Ok, I will try to tweak it. meanwhile you can give it a try as well.

Comment: Sure buddy. Doing the same. :)

Comment: I made some edits, you can now drag it along the `y-axis`. is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want. However, anyway to smoothen the flickering?

Comment: flickering? I am not noticing anything. :/

Comment: BTW, I just added the `origin` to the drag. can you check now?

Comment: Sure. In the meantime can you suggest something for this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326941/d3js-symbols-style-transition

Comment: sure, I will take a look.

Comment: @thisOneGuy I did not update the fiddle . I will update.

Comment: @thisOneGuy you can copy the call function and append to your text label function.

Comment: @thisOneGuy I just updated the fiddle. you can check now. http://jsfiddle.net/qv40gz5b/1/

Comment: Cool, just wondering how it all worked. Would be cool if the cursor changed and there were limits on the drag so it can't be dragged off the bar, but theyre quite easy to implement. Good job :)

Comment: Well, it is not difficult, the drag behaviour is just added to the `text` element. and I just change the `y` coordinate. we can restrict the `x` if we can determine the `rect` bars height. :)